# How to get GNU emacs buffers sorted alphabetically?

Tags: emacs, sorting, buffer

Somehow, I caused my GNU emacs v23.1.1 `list-buffers` to be sorted alphabetically through some key sequence or mouse click I typed by error.  How can I restore the normal order of buffers listed in order of last access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toggle sort *up* or *down* by clicking any column heading.

Comment: True! Do you know of any key combination to achieve the same?

Comment: I couldn't find any key bindings for sorting, in  `buff-menu.el`, for which: *"the single entry point is 'list-buffers'"* ..  The sort functions are `Buffer-menu-sort (column)`, `Buffer-menu-sort-by-column (&optional e)`, `Buffer-menu-make-sort-button (name column) `, but they all seem to be focused on mouse actions.

Comment: Hitting `S` appears to sort the buffer on the column at point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the standard `list-buffers`? It does not support sorting, as far as I know. On the other hand, `ibuffer` can sort the buffers, you can use <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) to cycle over various sort options.

Comment: Yes, `list-buffers` and somehow I caused it to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Next time you do so, press `C-h l` to see the last keys pressed.

Comment: I can confirm Peter O's answer: clicking on the column headings sorts by that column. This came in with Emacs 22.

Comment: `ibuffer` is nice, It seems to offer all that `list-buffer` does, and more. +1